# JQuery.getJson isn't triggered properly

Tags: php, javascript, json, dom

I am trying to use JSON for getting dynamic content to my webpage, using javascript. Something is not correct and I have problem figuring out what it can be. In firebug I can see that the JSON-data is retreived as it should. When looking in Firebug under "DOM", the URL I am accessing for the page (the actual page I have created, not the URL to JSON-data) is coloured red (see screenshot below). Here is my javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#target').click(function() {                 

            alert("At least I',m reached ");

            $.getJSON('http://localhost/timereporting/phpscriptlibrary/get_remaining_hours.php', function(data) {

                    document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML = "Divtext";
                    alert("Inside getJason");
            });
            alert("At least I',m done ");

        });
```

This is the significant part of my php file:

```
$json_string = "{\"activities\": "; 

$json_string = $json_string."[";

for ( $counter = 0; $counter < $num; $counter += 1) {

          $json_string = $json_string."[".mysql_result($rows,$counter,'date').", \"".mysql_result($rows,$counter,'activity_id')."\", ".mysql_result($rows,$counter,'hours')."]"; 

          if($counter != ($num-1)){
            $json_string = $json_string.", ";
          }

} 

$json_string = $json_string."]}";

echo $json_string;
```

I assume that "echo" is the way to "send" the JSON-data to the javascript?

One strange thing is that in firebug the JSON-data is presented in two different ways. If you look at the included screenshots below, the second one has dates like "1988" or similar while on the first one the dates are more complete like "2010-12-10". The first screenshot depicts how it should be and that's how I am trying to send it, and obviously it is received like this at some point.

How come my div-tag isn't updated with the date or that the alert inside the $.getJSON isn't triggered, only the alert before and after?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't create your JSON strings properly. Every string has to be enclosed in double quotes. But `2010-12-10` is not and jQuery evaluates this as `2010 - 12 - 10 = 1988`.

Don't build your string manually, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), something like:

```
$data = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
    $data[] = array($row['date'], intval($row['activity_id']), intval($row['hours']));
}

echo json_encode(array('activities' => $data));
```

Comment: allso it would help to set the right headers wouldn't it ? header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

Comment: Things like this save you tons of time in the long run and help reduce bugs.  Definitely use this tool or something similar to it.

Comment: @poelinca: I think it is not a must (and would work without), but it definitely helps.

Comment: Think of the headers as also acting like inline code comments.  Anyone looking at the code has just that much more code staring at them that says "This returns JSON".  Being explicit definitely isn't a bad thing.

Comment: ÅÅåhhhh...I did change place of two of the parameters, i forgot to move the double quotes... Thanks also for the json_encode tip, I will use it.